# How to solve OSError: [WinError 2] Impossibile finding specified file: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\chardetect.exe'

Tags: python, pip, oserror

As stated in the title, every time i try to install something via pip, at the end of the installation it gives me an error

```
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
  Rolling back uninstall of chardet
  Moving to c:\python39\lib\site-packages\chardet-4.0.0.dist-info\
   from C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~hardet-4.0.0.dist-info
  Moving to c:\python39\lib\site-packages\chardet\
   from C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~hardet

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\chardetect.exe' -> 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\chardetect.exe.deleteme'*
```

Already tried

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```

But it says

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\paolo\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (21.0.1)

I can't understand why and can't find anything on internet. Please Help!

Answer (score 4):

After the

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```

command, re-run the install.