# AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'api_type'

Tags: python, openai-api

I had a python program that ran fine about 2 months ago (February 2023).  However, I reran the program today (April 2023), and now I'm running into issues.  My python environment has not changed.

```
openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=7,
  temperature=0
)
```

The program returns an **AttributeError** that states **module 'openai' has no attribute 'api_type'**.  It appears OpenAI must have depreciated my library, and I no longer can run the code in its current form.  How can I correct this error?

Under guidance of other posts, I simply updated my package using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

Unfortunately, the update fails and issues the following issue:

```
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\normalizer.exe' -> 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\normalizer.exe.deleteme'
```

Without the update, the openai code in my program cannot properly run.

Comment: Give this command a shot `python -m pip install -U pip --user`, then try upgrade or reinstall opeani module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691204/how-to-solve-oserror-winerror-2-impossibile-finding-specified-file-c-pyth

Comment: Sorry, just to add, try installing the package as administrator (Win+R, cmd, shift+enter, Yes, `python -m pip install --upgrade openai`)